# how to handle NA's in sparsematrix in R?

Tags: r

i'm trying to find out N using sparsematrix on a dataset which is having structure numeric.

```
N=sparseMatrix(i=append_check[[1]], j=append_check[[2]], x=append_check[[3]])
```

> Error in sparseMatrix(i = append_check[[1]], j = append_check[[2]], x
>   = append_check[[3]]) :   NA's in (i,j) are not allowed

Comment: Try `append.check <- na.omit(append.check)`

Comment: I do not want to loose my observations or replace them with zero.

Comment: I don't think the `0` index will work on sparseMatrix

Comment: When I am running the code on R studio, it is working on data with NA but it is not working on R server. Any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: I am running it on R console.  So, I can't comment on R studio.  From my previous experience, it will not work with 0 index.  Then, why not remove those rows.